# Stopping a dplyr/tidyr chain mid-execution and saving calculation progress

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a written custom function that takes a while to run on a large dataset and sometimes stalls out. My function is a window function (e.g., `cumsum`). If I stop the execution all the data is lost. Is there a way in `tidyr` and `dplyr` to save the data as it goes along to avoid this?

My data is in wide format and I am running the function over groups (e.g., Products) and over many variables (e.g., Metrics).

```
   Product Year           a           b           c           d
1        A 2012 -0.54884514 -0.15416417  0.54861146  1.04147041
2        A 2013  1.22642587  1.43655028 -0.71433978  0.23523411
3        A 2014 -1.49161792  0.53356645  0.44964089 -0.01657906
4        A 2015 -0.72283864 -0.30601369 -0.04536668 -1.24809562
5        A 2016  0.41150740  1.42205301  0.59239525  1.82255169
6        B 2012  0.07279991  1.87163670  1.45773252 -1.93302885
7        B 2013  1.02705536 -2.70856122  0.57013708  1.35345098
8        B 2014  1.35513596  0.05818042 -0.41595725 -2.07142883
9        B 2015  0.40750419  0.13024750 -0.89163416  0.44227276
10       B 2016  0.25391609  0.02908517 -1.62128177  1.83811852
11       C 2012 -0.70568556  0.37254186 -0.61830412 -1.61228981
12       C 2013 -0.97811352  0.73741264 -0.60743864  0.12820628
13       C 2014 -0.20605945 -1.26239900 -0.21926510 -0.29185710
14       C 2015 -1.07297893  2.17374995 -0.29045520 -0.15203030
15       C 2016 -1.51221585  0.87294266  0.26420813 -0.70152124
16       D 2012  0.44717558  0.07587063  0.62215522  0.76882890
17       D 2013 -1.71815014  2.60236385  0.14437641 -0.60752707
18       D 2014  0.50659673 -0.57601702  0.09140279 -1.18971359
19       D 2015 -1.27493812 -0.76221085  0.58623989  0.37937413
20       D 2016  2.03280890 -0.39427715  0.29775332  0.88033461
```

If I use the tidy method, I can just `gather` the data and then `group_by`. This works, but I cannot stop mid-execution without losing all the progress.

```
# The tidy way
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Metric,Value,3:6) %>%
  group_by(Product,Metric) %>%
  mutate(Metric2 = paste0(Metric,2),
         Value2 = cumsum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Value, -Metric) %>% # I would love to leave the original metric in if possible
  spread(Metric2,Value2)
```

If I don't use the tidy method, I can stop the execution at anytime and the results to that point are saved.

```
# The non-tidy way
dt2 <- tibble()
#pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 4, initial = 0, style = 3)
for(i in 1:4) {
  single_product <- dt[which(dt$Product == unique(dt$Product)[i]),]
  for(j in 3:6) {
    single_metric <- single_product[,c(1:2,j)]
    single_metric[,paste0(colnames(single_metric[3]),2)] <- cumsum(single_metric[3])
    single_product <- left_join(single_product,single_metric)
  }
  dt2 <- bind_rows(dt2,single_product)
  #setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
}
```

Bonus points if we can add a progress bar. Here is the dummy data:

```
# The data
dt <- expand.grid(Product=LETTERS[1:4], Metric = letters[1:4], Year = 2012:2016)
dt$Value <- rnorm(nrow(dt))
dt <- dt %>%
  spread(Metric, Value)
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I can think of to save progress is to use a cache. In the code below, `memoize_fun` takes a function for computing a value (`value_fun`, and a function for computing a key for that value (`key_fun`). In this case, the key is the Product, and the value is the full data frame you want to compute for that product. I've added messages to show when the cache is being populated and used. Note that if the `do` statement takes more than a few seconds, dplyr should automatically add a progress bar. You should see this on the first run, where the runtime is artificially inflated using calls to `Sys.sleep`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
dt <- expand.grid(Product=LETTERS, Metric = letters[1:4], Year = 2012:2016)
dt$Value <- rnorm(nrow(dt))
dt <- dt %>%
  spread(Metric, Value)


my_cache <- list()
memoize_fun <- function(value_fun,  key_fun) {
    function(...) {
        key <- as.character(key_fun(...))
        message("Using key", deparse(key))
        assert_that(is.character(key))
        assert_that(length(key) == 1)
        if (! key %in% names(my_cache)) {
            message("Computing value for ", deparse(key))
            my_cache[[key]] <<- value_fun(...)
            Sys.sleep(1)
        } else {
            message("Re-using stored value for ", deparse(key))
        }
        return (my_cache[[key]])
    }
}

metrics <- colnames(dt)[3:6]

system.time({
    dt2 <- dt %>%
        group_by(Product) %>%
        do({
            value_fun <- . %>% cbind(., CumSum=transmute_all(.[metrics], cumsum))
            key_fun <- . %>% .$Product %>% .[1]
            memoize_fun(value_fun, key_fun)(.)
        })
})

## Run the same thing again to demonstrate that everything is cached
system.time({
    dt2 <- dt %>%
        group_by(Product) %>%
        do({
            value_fun <- . %>% cbind(., CumSum=transmute_all(.[metrics], cumsum))
            key_fun <- . %>% .$Product %>% .[1]
            memoize_fun(value_fun, key_fun)(.)
        })
})
```

We can also demonstrate that this works for restarting in the presence of random errors by adding a 50% chance of failure to each computation, and then wrapping it in code that keeps retrying until it reaches the end:

```
my_cache <- list() # Reset the cache
finished <- FALSE
tries <- 1
while (! finished) {
    message("Attempt number ", tries)
    tryCatch({
        dt2 <- dt %>%
            group_by(Product) %>%
            do({
                value_fun <- . %>% cbind(., CumSum=transmute_all(.[metrics], cumsum)) %T>%
                    { if (runif(1) > 0.5) stop("Random error")}
                key_fun <- . %>% .$Product %>% .[1]
                memoize_fun(value_fun, key_fun)(.)
            })
        finished <- TRUE
    },
    error=function(...) NULL)
    tries <- tries + 1
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that using `transmute_all`, `mutate_at`, or something similar as you did is also going to save quite a bit of time versus reshaping the table wide to long to wide again.